# Python Crash Course Space Invader Issue

Tags: python

I have ran to issues on creating the space invader on python. This is my code. I have a traceback error:

```
File "C:\Users\Deadl\Desktop\py4e\Python Crash Course 5\spaceinvader.py", 
    line 27, in <module> run_game()   
File "C:\Users\Deadl\Desktop\py4e\Python Crash Course 5\spaceinvader.py", 
    line 14, in run_game
    ship = Ship(screen)    
File "C:\Users\Deadl\Desktop\py4e\Python Crash Course 5\ship.py",
    line 7, in __init__    
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
pygame.error: Unsupported image format
```

Can someone help me out? I have checked my ship and settings, they were both alright. I created an images folder in my space invasion folder with the ship image as ship.bmp.

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    #Initialize the game and creates a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(screen)
    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        #Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different image format?

Comment: **pygame.error: Unsupported image format** ...  https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load  mentions it supports bmp though. Maybe something in your omitted Ship class is wonky? Did you use a graphics program and store it as .bmp with a .bmp suffix? renaming any old grafic file to bmp will not work (no offence if you are a grafix-wizard - what I have seen in questions ...)